# How to replace a group-of-groups RegExp in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have some text like this:

```
1|Some things|US|192||||||1||
2|Some other things|US|128|3|||5|1|1|3|
3|Whatever else|US|128||15||||||
```

And I'd like to replace it in Notepad++ with something like:

```
1|Some things|US|192|+++++1++
2|Some other things|US|128|3+++5+1+1+3+
3|Whatever else|US|128|+15++++++
```

But I couldn't find some proper way to do it. I managed to build a RegExp that matches the string:`US\|(\d+)\|((\d*)\|)+` but I couldn't find how to build the replacement string to match this group-of-groups approach.

The hard part for me was excluding the first number after the "US". The only way out I could see was replacing `(?<![a-zA-Z])\|(?![a-zA-Z])` for `+` and then replacing `US\|(\d+)\+` back to `US|\1|`.

Is it possible to do such a replacement with Notepad++'s builtin or TextFX's replacement tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\|US\|\d+\|)\d*\K\|
```

With `+` as replacement string.

For each line the scenario is the same:

- the first match uses the second branch of the alternation: `\|US\|\d+\|` and match the first pipe
- other matches use the first branch with the `\G` anchor that ensures the contiguity.
- when the last pipe is reached, the contiguity is broken and the first branch can't no more succeed.

The `\K` feature removes all previous matched characters from the match result and only the pipe is replaced.

Comment: This is twisting my mind, but works! Thanks for the explanation too! I didn't know of `\G` and `\K`.